# Android - Task is not running when it should

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am using Backendless to store my app user's data. Backendless only has the option to make either your email or username unique. I made my username field unique and that is what the user will use to log in. The emails can be reused so I am making a method before registration to check if the email exists.

This is the `createUser` method, this starts off and calls the method to check for email availability as soon as it starts:

```
private void createUser() {
    showProgressDialog();

    if (isEmailAvailable(inputEmail.getText().toString().trim())) {
        BackendlessUser user = new BackendlessUser();
        user.setProperty(BackendSettings.USERNAME_KEY, inputUsername.getText().toString().trim());
        user.setEmail(inputEmail.getText().toString().trim());
        user.setPassword(inputPassword.getText().toString());

        Backendless.UserService.register(user, new AsyncCallback<BackendlessUser>() {
            @Override
            public void handleResponse(BackendlessUser backendlessUser) {
                hideProgressDialog();
                Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, BackendSettings.REGISTER_SUCCESS_MESSAGE, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(CreateAccountActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void handleFault(BackendlessFault backendlessFault) {
                hideProgressDialog();
                String errorCode = backendlessFault.getCode();
                String errorMessage;
                switch (errorCode) {
                    case "3040":
                        errorMessage = BackendSettings.ERROR_3040;
                        break;
                    case "3033":
                        errorMessage = BackendSettings.ERROR_3033;
                        break;
                    default:
                        errorMessage = "An unknown error occurred. Try again.";
                }
                Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    } else {
        hideProgressDialog();
        Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, BackendSettings.ERROR_EMAIL_TAKEN, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This is the method that checks for the email availability:

```
private boolean isAvailable;
private boolean isEmailAvailable(String email) {
    isAvailable = false;

    String whereClause = "email = '" + email + "'";
    BackendlessDataQuery dataQuery = new BackendlessDataQuery();
    dataQuery.setWhereClause(whereClause);
    Backendless.Persistence.of(BackendlessUser.class).find(dataQuery, new AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<BackendlessUser>>() {
        @Override
        public void handleResponse(BackendlessCollection<BackendlessUser> userBackendlessCollection) {
            isAvailable = userBackendlessCollection.getData().isEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        public void handleFault(BackendlessFault backendlessFault) {
            Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, backendlessFault.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return isAvailable;
}
```

Okay, so I always get the message that the email is already taken, even if it is not. So I decided to put a `Toast` message in the `handleResponse` method for `isEmailAvailble`. I made it print if the email was available or not. So I first got the message from the else clause in `createUser` saying that the email was already taken and then I got the message from the `isEmailAvailable` method. It seems that the `isEmailAvailable` method is being ran afterwards. I am not sure what is going wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woa!
The error is in isEmailAvailable method.

Find if asyncronous method.
It works like that: you call it, it begins to work and returns immediately, before any actually results.
Later it calls the callback methods. So, when you do

```
    return isAvailable;
```

isAvailable is always false on that line because it is still not changed.

You should do some async work.
1. call Backendless.Persistence.of(BackendlessUser.class).find(...)
2. wait for answer. You will know the result only in

```
   public void handleResponse(BackendlessCollection<BackendlessUser> userBackendlessCollection) {
       isAvailable = userBackendlessCollection.getData().isEmpty();
   }
```

3. do the rest of job just after

```
    isAvailable = userBackendlessCollection.getData().isEmpty();
```

create a method doCreateUser, put the body of you "if" into it and call it from handleResponse, after isAvailable = userBackendlessCollection.getData().isEmpty();

use this code:

```
    private void createUser() {
        showProgressDialog();
        checkEmailAvailable(inputEmail.getText().toString().trim());
    }

    private void checkEmailAvailable(String email) {
        String whereClause = "email = '" + email + "'";
        BackendlessDataQuery dataQuery = new BackendlessDataQuery();
        dataQuery.setWhereClause(whereClause);
        Backendless.Persistence.of(BackendlessUser.class).find(dataQuery, new AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<BackendlessUser>>() {
            @Override
            public void handleResponse(BackendlessCollection<BackendlessUser> userBackendlessCollection) {
                isAvailable = userBackendlessCollection.getData().isEmpty();
                if (isAvailable){
                    doCreateuser();
                } else {
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, BackendSettings.ERROR_EMAIL_TAKEN, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void handleFault(BackendlessFault backendlessFault) {
                Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, backendlessFault.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                hideProgressDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    private void doCreateuser(){
        BackendlessUser user = new BackendlessUser();
        user.setProperty(BackendSettings.USERNAME_KEY, inputUsername.getText().toString().trim());
        user.setEmail(inputEmail.getText().toString().trim());
        user.setPassword(inputPassword.getText().toString());

        Backendless.UserService.register(user, new AsyncCallback<BackendlessUser>() {
            @Override
            public void handleResponse(BackendlessUser backendlessUser) {
                hideProgressDialog();
                Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, BackendSettings.REGISTER_SUCCESS_MESSAGE, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(CreateAccountActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void handleFault(BackendlessFault backendlessFault) {
                hideProgressDialog();
                String errorCode = backendlessFault.getCode();
                String errorMessage;
                switch (errorCode) {
                    case "3040":
                        errorMessage = BackendSettings.ERROR_3040;
                        break;
                    case "3033":
                        errorMessage = BackendSettings.ERROR_3033;
                        break;
                    default:
                        errorMessage = "An unknown error occurred. Try again.";
                }
                Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, so are you saying that from my create account button, I should call `isEmailAvailable` method instead of `createUser`?

Comment: you should first call isEmailAvailable. and leave. later, when a callback to isEmailAvailable is called, you should do the stuff.

Comment: Okay, it works great! I get why now. I had to wait to get the result back from Async task, the way I do that is by implementing the `if` statement directly inside the `handleResponse` method. It seems so simple, but couldn't have done it without your help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The calls to Backendless are asynchron and thats why your method always return the value `isAvailable` is initialised with(here false). You need to synchronize for example with a `Semaphore` to block before return the proper value.

```
private boolean isEmailAvailable(String email) {
boolean isAvailable = false;
String whereClause = "email = '" + email + "'";
final Semaphore s = new Semaphore(0);
BackendlessDataQuery dataQuery = new BackendlessDataQuery();
dataQuery.setWhereClause(whereClause);

Backendless.Persistence.of(BackendlessUser.class).find(dataQuery, new AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<BackendlessUser>>() {
    @Override
    public void handleResponse(BackendlessCollection<BackendlessUser> userBackendlessCollection) {
        isAvailable = userBackendlessCollection.getData().isEmpty();
        s.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleFault(BackendlessFault backendlessFault) {
        Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, backendlessFault.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        s.release();
    }
});
try{
    s.aquire();
}catch(Exception e){
}
return isAvailable;
```

}

Comment: This froze the application.